# Django contrib admin default admin and password

Tags: django

This may be a silly question. I start a new Django project as Document says, which only included an admin page. I start the server and use a web browser accessing the page. What can I enter in the username and password? Is their any place for me to config the default admin account?

Comment: run python manage.py createsuperuser , put the username and password

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can config using following command line in shell

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Basically you're creating superuser who can access the django admin panel.

Comment: How can I switch between local DB authentication and LDAP authentication then?

Comment: You can have 2 settings file. In one settings file you can point to local db and other one in other settings file. 

You can specify which settings file has to be picked by
    
python manage.py runserver --settings=<project_name>.settings.<settings file name>

Comment: Worth mentioning `python manage.py createsuperuser -h` shows you how to automate the name of the user, but you always have to set the password interactively.

Answer (score 31):

First you need to run migrate to change the admin username and password. Run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Then edit the username and password using

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Then give an username and password and a email.

Comment: If you're using python 3, the commands are still valid. just use `python3` instead.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to run for the first time then first do

```
python manage.py migrate
```

this will migrate all the data into migrate folder
then simply run

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to create a superuser to access django admin

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

just enter the username,email and password(password you entered is invisible to you in powershell but it saves the password)

Comment: where is it saved? How is it hashed? How to not check it into git?

Answer (score 2):

use this command python

```
manage.py createsuperuser

You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Username (leave blank to use 'chatru'): admin
Email address: admin@gmail.com
Password: 
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create superuser and add username, password manually like this:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser

You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): auth.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
Username (leave blank to use 'chatru'): admin
Email address: admin@gmail.com
Password: 
Password (again):
The password is too similar to the username.
This password is too short. It must contain at least 8 characters.
This password is too common.
Bypass password validation and create user anyway? [y/N]: y
Superuser created successfully.
```

Answer (score -1):

In the program settings make sure you have:

just following the BASE_DIR path definition
TEMPLATE_DIR = (Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, "your_templates_folder"))

and

in the same file under the template configuration, must include
'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],

and very importantly, run the settings.py file - I had endless struggles after making this change and not running the settings file.